# Swift: Cannot convert value type string to expected argument type nsmutablestring

Tags: regex, swift, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to use to replace substring using NSRegularExpression but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot convert value type string to expected argument type nsmutablestring
```

Here is my code:

```
let myString = "my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BB AA"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}",
                                     options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)

let range = NSMakeRange(0, house.characters.count)
var result:String = regex.replaceMatchesInString(myString, //<--here is I'm getting error
                                                 options: [],
                                                 range: range,
                                                 withTemplate: "***")
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or how to fix it?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for `NSRegularExpression replaceMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:`. The first parameter needs to be an `NSMutableString`, not `String`.

You can change your first line for `let myString` to create an `NSMutableString`.

```
let myString = NSMutableString(string: "my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BB AA")
```